# Facing Invalid security error on SOAPUI response

Tags: soapui, xml-namespaces, ws-security

I am unable to resolve this issue
Try basic Call, Tried execute with below WS- options

**Must Understand = None, Must Understand = True, Must Understand = False**

Response i get

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<s:Fault>
<faultcode xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
<faultstring xml:lang="en-GB">An error occurred when verifying security for the message.</faultstring>
</s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```